# heroku resque, run a specific queue on specific worker on heroku

Tags: heroku, resque

I have a question. I am using resque on heroku. There are 5 workers and 5 queues. 
Now, Can I run specific queue(lets say queue4) on specific worker(let's say worker 1).

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Resque requires that you set the QUEUE in an environment variable (or in the `.resque` file at the top of your project).
You cannot, on heroku, have different environment variables depending of a dyno.

What you can do, though, is the following, in your `Procfile` :

```
urgent: QUEUE=urgent rake environment resque:work
low: QUEUE=low rake environment resque:work
```

You will get two different workers and can scale them both separately depending of your needs.
They will both run similarly, but have different environment variables use different queues.

Answer (score 0):

if you use delayed_job this works

in Procfile.

worker_l:  bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=worker_l
worker_m:  bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=worker_m
worker_h:  bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=worker_h
worker_u:  bundle exec rake jobs:work QUEUE=worker_u

and then

handle_asynchronously :do_it, :queue => 'worker_h'